# Effective method to solve $\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x} -\sqrt[3]{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x} +\sqrt[3]{1-x}} = \frac{x(x^2+3)}{3x^2+1} $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, substitution

I want to know, is there an easy method to solve below equation $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x} -\sqrt[3]{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x} +\sqrt[3]{1-x}} = \frac{x(x^2+3)}{3x^2+1} $$ I tried it by plotting and find the solution $x=0,1,-1$ then I tried to solve it by sustitution, multiplying by $(\sqrt[3]{(1+x)^2}+\sqrt[3]{1+x} \sqrt[3]{1-x} +\sqrt[3]{(1-x)^2})$ and so on ...
but I got stuck in solving it normally.

I am thankful if anyone can show me the clue.

Implicit:  when I plot both sides , I feel if we name $$f(x)=\frac{(\sqrt[3]{1+x} -\sqrt[3]{1-x})}{(\sqrt[3]{1+x} +\sqrt[3]{1-x})}$$ then  $$f^{-1}= \frac{x(x^2+3)}{3x^2+1} $$  so It is an effective way to solve $$f(x)=f^{-1}(x)=x$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x} -\sqrt[3]{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x} +\sqrt[3]{1-x}} = \frac{x(x^2+3)}{3x^2+1} $$
Use [componendo-dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo):

$$ \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x} -\sqrt[3]{1-x} + (\sqrt[3]{1+x} +\sqrt[3]{1-x})}{\sqrt[3]{1+x} -\sqrt[3]{1-x} - (\sqrt[3]{1+x} +\sqrt[3]{1-x})} = \frac{x(x^2+3) + 3x^2+1}{x(x^2+3) -(3x^2+1)} $$

$$ \frac{2\sqrt[3]{1+x}}{-2\sqrt[3]{1-x}} = \frac{x^3+3x^2+3x+1}{x^3-3x^2+3x-1}$$
$$ -\sqrt[3]{\frac{{1+x}}{{1-x}}} = \frac{(x+1)^3}{(x-1)^3} = -\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^3$$

I think you can handle it from here

Comment: I think you missed a $+$ sign in line 2 $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x} -\sqrt[3]{1-x} + (\sqrt[3]{1+x} +  \sqrt[3]{1-x})}{\sqrt[3]{1+x} \to \pm \sqrt[3]{1-x} - (\sqrt[3]{1+x} +\sqrt[3]{1-x})} = \frac{x(x^2+3) + 3x^2+1}{x(x^2+3) -(3x^2+1)}
$$ am I right ?

Comment: @Khosrotash No, it should be a minus sign. I used the following fact: $$ \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} \implies \frac{a+b}{a-b} = \frac{c+d}{c-d}$$

Comment: ya , I got it, thank you for a nice Idea

Answer (score 0):

I think about it again , $$f(x)=\frac{(\sqrt[3]{1+x} -\sqrt[3]{1-x})}{(\sqrt[3]{1+x} +\sqrt[3]{1-x})}=\\\frac{(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} -1)}{(\sqrt[3]\frac{1+x}{1-x} +1)}$$so $$y=\frac{(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} -1)}{(\sqrt[3]\frac{1+x}{1-x} +1)}=\frac{a+1}{a-1}\\\to a=\frac{y+1}{y-1}\\\to  \sqrt[3]{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}=\frac{y+1}{y-1}\\\to x=y\\x=\frac{x(x^2+3)}{3x^2+1}
\\ \to x=0,1,-1$$